# Is "darkweb" one word or two words?

Tags: hyphenation, compound-words

I observed the word "darkweb" in newspapers of late, and wondered if it is one word or two words. I could not get a definite answer when I did a Google search. No one seems to have addressed this issue. Now, my specific question is, which is acceptable usage? - "darkweb", "dark-web" or "dark web"?

Comment: Google finds 300 times more hits for 'dark web ' than 'darkweb'. Since that tells me that darkweb is a made-up word, I ask whether the single word carries meaning that the original two do not. If not, I stay with tradition. Examples are online, website, upload, that took on distinct meaning and acceptance as new words  we needed.

Comment: I'd be inclined to use "dark web" for the noun and "darkweb" for the adjective.

Comment: Various easily accessible dictionaries **have** addressed this issue.